# Merging lines of a text file and sorting based on the order of elements in another text file

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have two unsorted text files like below which do not necessarily have the same number of lines:

in A.txt we only have one unique element per line:

```
a7
a1
a5
a2
a6
a8
a4
```

and in B.txt we have one unique element pair in each line:

```
a1 a2
a7 a6
a1 a5
a5 a8
a1 a4
a2 a1
a4 a5
a6 a7
a8 a2
```

I first want to merge lines of B.txt in a way if there are multiple pairs with common first element, the second elements must be concatenated like:

TempAB.txt

```
a1 a2 a5 a4
a7 a6
a5 a8
a2 a1
a4 a5
a6 a7
a8 a2
```

and then the final output must be in the same order as A.txt like:

AB.txt

```
a7 a6
a1 a2 a5 a4
a5 a8
a2 a1
a6 a7
a8 a2
a4 a5
```

Any suggestion using awk?

Comment: Do you actually need that intermediate file or do you just think that would be the necessary approach to producing your final file? What would you want done with a line in B.txt that started with a value not present in A.txt, e.g. `a3` or can that simply never happen?

Comment: Found the code for the first part at http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/208027-merge-multiple-lines-same-file-common-key-using-awk.html .... awk 's != $1 || NR ==1{s=$1;if(p){print p};p=$0;next}
{sub($1,"",$0);p=p""$0;}END{print p}' B.txt

Comment: @ Ed Morton: No, it is not necessary. I just wanted the explain step by step.

Comment: Don't assume awk code you find on any web site or forum, including this one, is reasonable unless you get it from newsgroup comp.lang.awk where it will have been reviewed by all of the awk experts. That snippet you posted is not reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following `awk` one-liners:

To create your temp data:

```
awk '{a[$1] = (a[$1]?a[$1] FS $2:$2)}END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}' b.txt
a1 a2 a5 a4
a2 a1
a4 a5
a5 a8
a6 a7
a7 a6
a8 a2
```

You can re-direct the output to another file say `b.tmp`.

To achieve second output, you can do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print (($1 in a) ? a[$1] : $1)}' b.tmp a.txt 
a7 a6
a1 a2 a5 a4
a5 a8
a2 a1
a6 a7
a8 a2
a4 a5
```

---

If you don't really need the intermediate file, then you can by-pass that and just do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1]FS$2:$0);next}{print(($1 in a)?a[$1]:$1)}' b.txt a.txt 
a7 a6
a1 a2 a5 a4
a5 a8
a2 a1
a6 a7
a8 a2
a4 a5
```

Comment: Just be aware it'd fail to populate `a[]` if the `$1` value ever evaluates to numeric zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=($1 in a?a[$1] FS:"")$2; next} {print $1, a[$1]}' B.txt A.txt
a7 a6
a1 a2 a5 a4
a5 a8
a2 a1
a6 a7
a8 a2
a4 a5
```

Comment: and a +1 for handling the [special case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452367/merging-lines-of-a-text-file-and-sorting-based-on-the-order-of-elements-in-anoth/25452503#comment39714804_25452503).

Comment: Thanks, I threw one your way too. One special case neither of us handled is where a `$1` from B.txt never appears in A.txt but the OP hasn't told us if/how that should be handled anyway.

Comment: Yea, I thought of deleting the array entries and handle those in the `END` block but didn't want to over complicate it. `:)`

Comment: Right, that's what I'd do too.